# Orthogonal polynomial approximation of any function

Tags: polynomials, approximation, approximation-theory, orthogonal-polynomials, numerical-calculus

Any nonlinear function $f(x)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be approximated by using orthogonal polynomial approximation 
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{N_f} b_i q_i(x), 
\end{equation}
where $N_f$ is the maximum order of approximation. $b_i$  are the coefficient, and $q_i(x)$ are orthogonal polynomial, and it satisfies
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
<q_i(x), q_j(x)> & = 0_{n\times n} \hspace{0.5 cm}  I \neq j \\&
= I_{n\times n} \hspace{0.5 cm}  I = j
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The coefficient $b_i$ can be calculated as
$$b_i = \int f(x) q_i^T(x) dx. $$

My problem is that I did not find more literature on multidimensional polynomial approximation. I just want to know, what will be the dimension of the $b_i$ and $q_i(x)$. 
I think the $q_i(x)$ will be of dimension $n\times 1$, and the dimension of $b_i$ is $n \times n$. But I don't know, I am doing right or not.

Any suggestion will be great help to me.